# Incorrect results with Poisson regression using bambi?

Tags: python-3.x, poisson, pymc3, bambi

I am giving [bambi](https://github.com/bambinos/bambi) (version 0.1.0) a try for a simple Poisson regression model. However the results differ when compared to straight pymc3 or statsmodels implementations, and I cannot seem to figure out how to interpret the coefficients that bambi gives me. The test code is below. Did I specify the model wrong, or should I not rely on the automatic priors of bambi?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import pandas
import patsy
import statsmodels
import pymc3
import bambi

%matplotlib inline

# generate data
num_subjects = 4
mu = [5, 8, 10, 11]
num_samples = [43, 60, 56, 38]

counts = [scipy.stats.poisson.rvs(m,size=n,random_state=m) for m,n in zip(mu,num_samples)]
counts = np.concatenate(counts)
subject = np.repeat(np.arange(num_subjects), num_samples)

df = pandas.DataFrame( np.vstack([subject,counts]).T, columns=['subject','counts'])

# sample means
print( df.groupby('subject').mean() )

# subject 0 = 5.0
# subject 1 = 7.4
# subject 2 = 9.5
# subject 3 = 10.0


# fit with bambi
model_bambi = bambi.Model(df)
result_bambi = model_bambi.fit('counts ~ C(subject)', categorical=['subject'], family='poisson', chains=2)

print(result_bambi.summary(hpd=None, diagnostics=None))

# resulting posterior means:
# Intercept        9.3310 -> ?
# C(subject)[T.1]  3.8171 -> ?
# C(subject)[T.2]  4.4419 -> ?
# C(subject)[T.3]  3.8652 -> ?


# fit directly with pymc3
with pymc3.Model() as model_pymc3:
    pymc3.glm.GLM.from_formula("counts ~ C(subject)", df, family=pymc3.glm.families.Poisson())
    trace = pymc3.sample(2000, njobs=2, tune=500)

pymc3.plot_posterior(trace, varnames=[x for x in trace.varnames if x[:2]!='mu']);

# resulting posterior means:
# Intercept        1.6065 -> mu = 5.0 = exp(1.6065) 
# C(subject)[T.1]  0.3990 -> mu = 7.4 = exp(1.6065+0.3990)
# C(subject)[T.2]  0.6477 -> mu = 9.5 = exp(1.6065+0.6477)
# C(subject)[T.3]  0.6977 -> mu = 10.0 = exp(1.6065+0.6977)


# fit with statsmodels
my, mx = patsy.dmatrices( "counts ~ C(subject)", df, NA_action='raise')
model_sm = statsmodels.api.GLM(my, mx, family=statsmodels.api.families.Poisson())
result_sm = model_sm.fit()

print(result_sm.summary())

# resulting posterior means:
# Intercept        1.6094 -> mu = 5.0 = exp(1.6094) 
# C(subject)[T.1]  0.3965 -> mu = 7.4 = exp(1.6094+0.3965)
# C(subject)[T.2]  0.6456 -> mu = 9.5 = exp(1.6094+0.6456)
# C(subject)[T.3]  0.6958 -> mu = 10.0 = exp(1.6094+0.6958)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies for the (very) slow reply; I wasn't subscribed to the [bambi] tag (but am now), and only just saw this. This is indeed a bug (details are [here](https://github.com/bambinos/bambi/issues/111)). I just opened a PR for it, so if you clone from the repo, the problem should be solved (and I'll issue a new PyPI release sortly). I realize this is probably not much use to you at this point, but thanks for flagging it anyway. If you run into any similar issues in future, please [open an issue](https://github.com/bambinos/bambi/issues) on the GitHub repo, as this definitely falls into bug territory.